# Sails.js model acces by string name

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Is there any way to access models in sails by its name being contained in a string?

for example, if I want to create a user, instead of doing

```
User.create({name: 'martin'});
```

I need to do something like

```
sails['User'].create({name: 'martin'});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All references to models are stored in globally accessible object **sails.models**. You can access any of your model using the array literal notation [].

```
var model = sails.models['users'];
model.create({name: 'martin'});
```

The same rule applies to controllers and services.

Comment: Also, note that accessing sails directly is hidden by default in latest version of sails. You will have to set sails : true in config/globals to access the sails.models

Comment: thanks for the answer. I found another solution writing:
`global['users'].create....`
Which is better?

Comment: I think both are fine.
The reason why I prefer using sails.models['users'] over globals['users'] is that you can still access your instances via sails.models even if you turn off exposing your app's models in config/globals.js file. (As @mandeep_m91 mentioned above, don't forget to set sails:true, otherwise you won't be able to access anything)

Comment: For my case sails.models['users'] is working but sails.models['Users'] not working.